# Are there any power outlets available in SNCF's Intercités de Nuit?

Tags: trains, france, power, night-transport, sncf

Are there any power outlets available inside SNCF's Intercités de Nuit? Ideally I'd like to know about both second and first class sleeper compartments, and any other possible locations.

Comment: Looks like it isn't always the case. Some trains seem to have some, some not... You'd better call the SNCF to get the answer.

Comment: In first class there are always outlets (at least one for two seats/beds), in second it depends if the train is new or not

Comment: @Boris What do you mean by two seats/beds?

Comment: @JoErNanO it means in the middle between two seats.. so one outlet is shared..

Comment: They exist only in the bathrooms.

Comment: @gerrit There are some in the hallways too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post on the forum of the french railway company SNCF](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/216717-eclairage-individuel-et-prise-electrique-intercite), you can find power oulets in the  hallway. Even the [incleanable seats do not feature power outlets](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/326610-prises-electriques-siege-inclinable-train-intercites-nuit-aller-retour-paris-aix-bains).

If you plan to use the plugs in the hallway, a good idea suggested by [this blog](http://www.travel-me-happy.com/2014/12/10-conseils-eviter-les-galeres-en-train-de-nuit/) is to take a power strip along with you. Indeed, you may not be the only one in need of a plug!

Answer (score 5):

No, I'm afraid there are no power outlets in these trains except in the bathrooms & in the hallway... 
You can still take a portable battery with you to charge your phone... during the night.